# VB: What is missing in scripting host while it is present in "full" VB?

Tags: vba, programming-languages, qtp, wsh

When programming (scripting) in VB scripting host, how can I learn what is implemented and what not?

For example, records (or: the `structure` keyword) are not implemented, but classes (or: the `class` keyword) isn't.

`Dim as <Type>` is not allowed, as are all "`as`" phrases.

You can create properties in classes, but not "`as`" anything, too.

You cannot inherit from a base class (the "`Inherits`" keyword is not known).

And so on.

I see the scripting host is a *scripting* host, so it might make sense to keep its functionality limited.

However, I do not see those limitations documented somewhere in an accessible, or even logcial way, giving all that a meaning. Currently, I am forced to stick to a trial-and-error workflow, plus separate lookups in QTPs online help for every detail I think of (and I might discover others which I forget currently). Is this the reality that Microsoft designed, or am i missing the point?

The question comes up with QTP, which uses Windows scripting host as its scripting language. Sure I can look up each and every detail I am looking for -- but, and these are my main questions:

**Where can I find a detailed list, or table, of *language* differences between the various VBA dialects (and versions?) that covers scripting host as well?**

**Can one give a (simple) reasoning for what is included in scripting host and what not?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[VBScript Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt.aspx) on MSDN covers all statements, keywords, functions and other language elements of VBScript. I always refer to it to recollect the exact syntax.

MSDN also has feature comparison guides for VBScript vs. VBA vs. Visual Basic:

- [VBScript Features not in Visual Basic for Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801s9ax8.aspx)
- [Visual Basic for Applications Features Not In VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30593abb.aspx)
- [Key Differences Between Visual Basic for Applications and VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970436.aspx)
- [VBScript Versus Visual Basic and VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139970.aspx#odc_dapbasics_vbsvba)

Comment: BANG! Full hit, enemy doooown. Thanks.

Comment: Mhmmm...anybody knows why all of the documents Helen provided links to do not mention inheritance?

Comment: Because, sadly enough, inheritance isn't possible in VBScript/QTP. Even using a class outside a module/QFL is not directly possible. (There are solutions for that: You can create a public (global) variable and assign a class to it inside the module. This variable acts as a singleton. An even more elegant solution is creating a public function that returns an instance of the class; the function can act as a class instantiator, even with parameters.)